# Read/write fixed size ints and strings to/from ByteBuffer for Dart binary websocket

Tags: javascript, binary, websocket, dart

I want to write a dart websocket client (via dart2js and dart:html) that reads and writes custom binary messages.  I figure when binaryType is set to 'arraybuffer' the incoming MessageEvent.data is a ByteBuffer from the typed_data dart package.  Knowing the incoming byte structure, I want to, say, read off two bytes as a uint16.  Conversely I need to add, say, a uint16 to the outgoing buffer.  What would be the specific mechanics in this case?  How in the same in/out buffer would I read/write a string?

There doesn't seem to be too many recent examples of dart binary websockets, I'd like to do something like [this guy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/) did with DataStream for javascript, for dart, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You already found the correct library (`typed_data`). Now just use it's classes (especially `ByteData`) to put data in a buffer or read data from a buffer.

E.g. to read two uint16 from the received buffer:

```dart
if ((event.data as ByteBuffer).lengthInBytes < 4) { // ignore packet }
ByteData bd = ByteData.view(event.data, 0, (event.data as ByteBuffer).lengthInBytes);
int first = bd.getUint16(0);
int second = bd.getUint16(2);
```

And to send two uint16:

```dart
Uint8List newBuffer = new Uint8List(4);
ByteData newBufferView = new ByteData.view(newBuffer.buffer, 0);
newBufferView.setUint16(0, 24);
newBufferView.setUint16(0, 4321);
socket.sendTypedData(newBuffer);
```

For reading and writing strings look at `dart:convert`s Codecs like `Utf8Codec` that can read and write a String from/to a list of bytes.